# Does updating a record using the same value create a change in session

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy and I have a table Person

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250))
    surname = Column(String(250))
```

I have the following records

```
per_1 = Person(name='James', surname='Baker')
per_2 = Person(name='Jack', surname='Andrew')
```

As far as  **performance** is concerned, i am wondering whether

```
per_1.name = 'James'
session.commit()
```

is the same as

```
if per_1.name != 'James':
    per_1.name = 'James'

session.commit()
```

More precisely does `per_1` name update using the same value create a change in session that needs to be committed or not?

For those wondering why I need such a change, I input a record to user and he has to change some attributes and (click) update. 
I would like to know if I updating the entire record is the same as  looking for attributes that have been changed and update them only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can check this by inspecting [session.dirty](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.dirty) after assigning the value.  If the instance is in `session.dirty` then SQLAlchemy has logged that the the instance has been changed.  At flush time SQLAlchemy checks whether the instance has actually changed relative to the values in the database (see [session.is_modified](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.is_modified)).

This code

```py
with Session() as session:
    q = sa.select(Person).where(
        Person.name == 'James', Person.surname == 'Baker'
    )
    (per_1,) = session.execute(q).first()
    print(f'Before {session.dirty=}')
    per_1.name = 'James'
    print(f'After {session.dirty=}')
    print(f'{session.is_modified(per_1)=}')
    session.commit()
```

produces this output:

```
2021-10-03 09:54:54,794 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-10-03 09:54:54,797 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT person.id, person.name, person.surname 
FROM person 
WHERE person.name = ? AND person.surname = ?
2021-10-03 09:54:54,797 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00025s] ('James', 'Baker')
Before session.dirty=IdentitySet([])
After session.dirty=IdentitySet([<__main__.Person object at 0x7f4c26141730>])
session.is_modified(per_1)=False
2021-10-03 09:54:54,798 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

demonstrating that:

- the instance is added to `session.dirty` even though the new value is the same as the old.
- the assignment does not cause an `UPDATE` statement to be sent to the database.

However there are circumstances in which an `UPDATE` may be sent even if there is no net change :

> Scalar attributes may not have recorded the previously set value when a new value was applied, if the attribute was not loaded, or was expired, at the time the new value was received - in these cases, the attribute is assumed to have a change, even if there is ultimately no net change against its database value. SQLAlchemy in most cases does not need the “old” value when a set event occurs, so it skips the expense of a SQL call if the old value isn’t present, based on the assumption that an UPDATE of the scalar value is usually needed, and in those few cases where it isn’t, is less expensive on average than issuing a defensive SELECT.